# Change action bar colors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to change the colors of the action bar, but when I change these data in the Android app, it does not change colors dynamically (unlike in iOS).

I need when I change the default color of the action bar to white (background color) the system will automatically change the title and return arrow colors to black (they are white and invisible). As I said above, in the iOS app only with this code the system already makes this switch automatically, however for Android I do not know how to do this same effect.

Follow the code below:

```
private void ChangeActionBarColor()
{
    var navigationPage = Detail as NavigationPage;
    navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Ambiente.Instance.NavigationColor;
    navigationPage.BarTextColor = Ambiente.Instance.NavigationItemColor;
    Title = Ambiente.Instance.NavigationTitle;
}
```

Comment: If you override OnAppearing in your MasterDetailPage it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom theme in droid/resource/styles.xml. and also need to apply this theme in your MainActivity

**Apply Theme on MainActivity**

```
[Activity(Label = "YourProject.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

**Add a custom theme in Style.XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <!-- You can also set icon, Title color -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarPopupTheme">@style/CustomActionBarPopupTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomActionBarPopupTheme" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**For more understanding**

[image]

Comment: This did not work, actionBar was white but the icon too.

Comment: add **<item name="textColorPrimary">#000000</item>** in style.

Comment: this causes the following error:

Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColorPrimary'.

Comment: as I said, the project does not run with this line.

Comment: try it **<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>**

Comment: I did the build, but even so, this does not show how to change at runtime, since I have a style already created being used by default, and I need this color change to occur during project execution, as I do in the code entered in the question. But for Android the exchange does not happen in relation to the colors of the texts, but in BarBackgroundColor is changing the color as desired. And the color on ActionBar is not changed... :(

Comment: @LuizNegrini You can define multiple themes and change the theme on button click.