# How to change the color of the menu icon on the MasterPageDetalis xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a project and need to change the menu icon, but I have not found a solution yet. How do I change the color of the menu icon in MasterPageDetalis xamarin.forms?

[image]

Comment: have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/46405023/1616738

Comment: Encontrei uma maneira fácil de resolver essa situação, neste link:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870132/how-to-change-color-of-hamburger-icon-in-material-design-navigation-drawer/31870783#31870783)

Answer (score 6):

Change in your base theme from style.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        </style>
        <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
            <item name="spinBars">true</item>
            <item name="color">@color/green</item>
        </style>
```

Please suggest me if i'm wrong

Comment: It works, thx, but it's not necessary specify the spinBars property

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Forms you would change the ActionBar color (and text color) like this:

```
var navigon = new NavigationPage(new WebViewPage());
    navigon.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Teal;
    navigon.BarTextColor = Color.White;
```

If you using MasterDetailPage you use override OnAppearing in your MasterDetailPage it should work.

Comment: changed the color of the bar and the text in it, but wanted to change the color of the menu icon.

Comment: navigon.BarTextColor is set color both icon and text for action bar if you want change only icon color use <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item> in android project styles.xml for android